# c# class serialization with property based on Control

Tags: c#, serialization, controls

Having class called PanelGroup and it has property called ElementControl whose type is Control. As I know Control is not Serializable, then what is recommended practise having this class to be serialized? Thanks.

```
public class PanelGroup
{
    public PanelGroup(FormElementGroupBase parentElement) : base(parentElement)
    {
        Intialize();
    }

    public PanelGroup(FormElementGroupBase parentElement, int id, string name, bool isVertical) : base(parentElement, id, name)
    {
        Intialize();
        IsVertical = isVertical;
    }

    private void Intialize()
    {
        this.ItemType = DomainItemTypes.PANEL_GROUP;
        this.ElementControl = new PanelControl();
        this.ElementControl.MinimumSize = new Size(50, 50);
        (this.ElementControl as PanelControl).AutoSize = true;
        (this.ElementControl as PanelControl).AutoSizeMode = System.Windows.Forms.AutoSizeMode.GrowAndShrink;

        if (ParentElement != null)
        {
            ParentElement.ElementControl.Controls.Add(this.ElementControl);
        };

        this.ElementControl.AllowDrop = true;
        this.ElementControl.MouseUp += new System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventHandler(this.Control_OnMouseUp);
        this.ElementControl.MouseDown += new System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventHandler(this.Control_OnMouseDown);
        this.ElementControl.KeyDown += new KeyEventHandler(this.Control_OnKeyDown);
        this.ElementControl.DragDrop += new DragEventHandler(OnDragDrop);
        this.ElementControl.DragOver += new DragEventHandler(OnDragOver);
    }

    [Browsable(false)]
    public override string NamePrefix
    {
        get { return "PanelGroup"; }

    }

    internal sealed override void Highlight()
    {
        (this.ElementControl as PanelControl).Appearance.BorderColor = SelectionColor;
    }
}
```

Comment: What is your expected outcome? If you serialize and deserialize a PanelGroup object, do you expect ElementControl to be null? Or do you expect it to be filled in with all of your relevant properties set to match the pre-serialization value?

Answer (score 0):

You have a few options. The easiest is to put a [NonSerialized] attribute on your ElementControl property, which just means it will be skipped when you serialize your PanelGroup. That results in you losing the value of ElementControl when you deserialize and reserialize the property.

Another option is to serialize your object manually (see [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ty01x675(v=vs.110).aspx)), but this can take a ton of work.

The best option, as usual when you run into this kind of problem, is to refactor it away. There's really no reason for a non-control class to ever have an instance of a control class in it. Your domain code (meaning custom classes you create to represent real concepts) should be separate from your UI. You may need to have properties which represent all the data needed to recreate the control later, but you can do that with no dependencies on any UI-specific implementation details like the Control class.

Comment: If I refactor it away as you say, then I have to maintain another object model in order to manage UI events like "OnDragDrop", "OnDragOver" etc and there are must be relationship between this Control Collection and Object (PanelGroup etc) collection.

Comment: That's correct - you would have a separate model responsible for UI logic while this class represents domain or business logic. There may be some relationships between them but that separation is still better overall. Take a look at MVP, MVC, MVVM patterns for some examples of this same root concept.